# Ways of retrieving previous value of State in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: ""
  });

function handleOnChange(event) {

const newValue = event.target.value;
const inputName = event.target.name;
```

I am taking input from a react form and the form has 2 inputs- fName and lName. Now I found that I can update the first Name and the last Name in both of the following ways.

```
setFullName((preValue) => {
      if (inputName === "fName") {
        return { ...preValue, fName: newValue };
      } else if (inputName === "lName") {
        return { ...preValue, lName: newValue };
      }
)
```

VS

```
if (inputName === "lName") setFullName({ ...fullName, lName: newValue });
else if (inputName === "fName") setFullName({ ...fullName, fName: newValue });
```

But when I see examples on the internet, I see that everyone is accessing the previous value of state by using a callback function (i.e the first method). Is there any particular advantage in doing so?

Comment: Yes, quoting from React : During subsequent re-renders, the first value returned by useState will always be the most recent state after applying updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases there won't be a meaningful difference.  The majority of tutorials cover simple state updates, and indeed the majority of logic I've seen/written in React is mostly simple state updates.  (After all, building many simple components is better than building few complex components.)

Sometimes, however, the state updates aren't as simple.  Sometimes the logic batches up multiple state updates.  As a contrived example, consider this logic:

```
if (editedFirstName) {
  setUser({ ...user, firstName: newFirstName });
}
if (editedLastName) {
  setUser({ ...user, lastName: newLastName });
}
```

Ignoring for a moment what UX drives this or whether or not there's a better way to update the object, what we have here are two different state updates potentially taking place in the same operation.  These updates will be batched and processed as part of the same re-render operation.

But what would be the result of these two state updates?  The latter one will clobber the former one, so `firstName` was never updated in the `User` state object.  Both state updates were processed, but the second one used the `firstName` value available at the time the component rendered, *not* the `firstName` value set by the first state update.

This is where the callback becomes useful:

```
if (editedFirstName) {
  setUser(prev => ({ ...prev, firstName: newFirstName }));
}
if (editedLastName) {
  setUser(prev => ({ ...prev, lastName: newLastName }));
}
```

Now both state updates can be successfully applied.  This is because, when batched, each subsequent update makes use of the previously updated state in that batch, not just the state which was available when the component rendered.

The callback structure simply allows us to make use of whatever value the state *will have* when the update is processed, rather than whatever value the state *already has* when the update is batched/queued.